# adding children to view-model at runtime in Aurelia

Tags: typescript, aurelia

I have a template that looks like this for `component.html`

```
<template>
  <div>${someBoundProperty}</div>
  <slot></slot>
</template>
```

It should be used as this in `app.html`:

```
<div>
  <component some-bound-property="text here">
    <component some-bound-property="more text"></component>
    <component some-bound-property="and more text"></component>
  </component>
</div>
```

and here is `component.ts`

```
export class ComponentCustomElement {
  @bindable someBoundProperty: string;
  @children('component') subComponents: ComponentCustomeElement[] = []
}
```

All the way to this point everything is working as expected.
Is there a way in aurelia to add children to my array at runtime within my view-model like the following inside `component.ts`?:

```
attached() {
  var newItem = new ComponentCustomElement();
  newItem.someBoundProperty = "my custom text";

  this.subComponents.push(newItem);
}
```

Of course adding an item to the array will not produce anything on the visual 
side. Is there a way to build the view and new view-model and push it to Aurelia to process?

Comment: This is one of the requested feature in vCurrent. At the moment, to do this, you kind of have manage everything on your own, including invoking correct life cycle.

Comment: @bigopon, do you know where is this being tracked?

Comment: It's in multiple places, but the oldest one would be this https://github.com/aurelia/templating/issues/458 Note that you can always do this, in Repeat custom attribute or if Custom attribute style, but it's a bit of a ceremony. We will try to tackle this in vNext.